# Microsoft Power Bi - Filtrando em back-end

Tags: powerbi

Olá. 
Estou começando a estudar o Power BI da Microsoft agora, e gostaria de ajuda em uma dúvida. 
Primeiramente eu criei um excel como fonte de dados:

[image: Fonte de dados]

Depois eu criei um conjunto de dados e um relatório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo certo até aqui. Estou usando a solução de exemplo que a Microsoft disponibiliza no https://app.powerbi.com/embedsetup. Agora eu gostaria de filtrar em back-end esse relatório.

Exemplo: Quando ele for chamado na minha aplicação, eu passe para ele um ID em back-end, e ele já filtre o relatório mostrando-o apenas com as informações pertinente aquele ID.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso da imagem acima, ele exibiria APENAS a informação do Id 5. Sem aparecer as outras que aparecem ali sem estarem selecionadas.

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Grato.

**ADICIONANDO INFORMAÇÕES:**
O link que o PowerBi Embed gera no back-end é diferente, e o filtro que testamos na resposta abaixo não funciona. Alguma dica de como resolver?

```
No EmbedService temos o código:
// Generate Embed Configuration.
m_embedConfig.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
m_embedConfig.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
```

Consegui resolver esse problema alterando no EmbedService a criação da URL, adicionando:

```
?rs:embed=true&filter=table/column eq 'filtervalue'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso voce vai ter de complementar a sua URL com o seguinte complemento:

```
..URL?filter=Table/Field eq 'value'
```

Algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Observações importante:*

- Os itens de tabela (Table) e campos (Field), são CASE SENSITIVE, o valor não é;
- Campos que não aparecem na visualização do relatório ainda podem ser filtrados.

**Links que podem te auxiliar nas suas dúvidas:**

[Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters)

[Easily embed secure Power BI reports in your internal portals or websites](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/)

[How to pass parameter to PowerBI Embedded Report](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/How-to-pass-parameter-to-PowerBI-Embedded-Report/idi-p/604940)

Para encontrar o nome da sua tabela, basta olha o menu FIELDS, no canto direito do seu powerbi quando estiver na aba que mostra o seu painel.

Nesse exemplo temos 4 tabelas: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria a Tabela?

Comment: A Tabela é o nome da estrutura onde voce colocou suas colunas, no seu exemplo ('id, 'nome' e 'valor')

Comment: No caso ficaria:    ?filter=Nome/Field eq 'Um'    .Porém não funcionou aqui.

Comment: é que voce esta colocando o nome da coluna ao invés do nome da tabela

Comment: Deveria ser ?filter=(O NOME DA SUA TABELA)/Nome eq 'Um'

Comment: Sim, eu não sei qual o nome da minha tabela. Onde fica essa info?

Comment: adicionei um adendo na resposta para voce encontrar

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Boa! Se possível marque a resposta como resolvida, para que outros também possam ser auxiliados. E bem vindo a comunidade :)

Comment: Oi Clayton, poderia me ajudar em outra pergunta sobre PowerBi? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439386/powerbi-utilizar-conex%c3%a3o-databasecontext-e-em-tempo-real

Answer (score 0):

O link que o PowerBi Embed gera no back-end é diferente, e o filtro que testamos acima não funciona. Alguma dica de como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No EmbedService temos o código:

```
// Generate Embed Configuration.
m_embedConfig.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
m_embedConfig.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
```

Comment: Consegui resolver esse problema alterando no EmbedService a criação da URL, adicionando:   ?rs:embed=true&filter=table/column eq 'filtervalue'.